# Rectangular Grid Sum

Tags: combinatorics

We have a m*n grid . Each entry in this grid is any number from 0 to n-1.

Task : Calculate the number of ways of choosing m numbers from grid such that their sum is factor of n.

Condition : If i choose a number Aij(ith row ,jth column) ,then i can't choose any other number from that row and that column.

My approach ---  I used backtracking approach and tried all the possibilities.
But it is too slow. I am looking for other optimal method to count the ways.